# Symfony Ajax same origin policy

Tags: ajax, symfony, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am trying to send an AJAX request from the domain: 127.0.0.1:8000 to localhost:8000. This call is ending in an

> Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

I have add an listener, which is sending the right headers for the origin problem:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

/**
 * Class CorsListener is handling on Kernel response header actions
 * @package AppBundle\Listener
 */
class CorsListener {
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // allow this only for the tracking URL
        /*if(strpos($request->getHost(), 'api.') === false) {
            return;
        }*/
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

But even the headers, you can see in the image below, it is not possible to become the request.

Some help?

[image]

Comment: Your PHP code needs explicit handling for OPTIONS requests. It’s not enough to just have “OPTIONS” in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods response-header value. The only effect that header value has is on the client side, in browsers. The problem you have is on the server side, and unrelated to your CORS-headers config. You need to have explicit code for handling OPTIONS requests; that code just needs to send a 200 OK response that includes the headers you already have configured (with the missing comma added, as noted below).

Comment: try this https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle. I think this still best solution for Symfony.

Comment: I concur NelmioCorsBundle makes it really easy to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma

```
$event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE OPTIONS');
```

Should be

```
$event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

`DELETE` and `OPTIONS` are two separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had to allow the OPTIONS method in my Symfony Controller:

```
* @Method({"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"})
```

Comment: BTW: I have now 2 requests to my server. One for OPTIONS and one for POST. Is this right?

Comment: Commenting on your own post, doesn't notify others ^^ I'll answer it for people that may read this: Yes it is normal, OPTIONS call just looks for the OPTIONS first before executing the actual call method.